# SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Network is unreachable, errno = 101)

Tags: flutter, mqtt

I'm using Flutter, and having this problem when I run the code using emulator. Before this, It can be run without any error tho.. This is what it says in the console..

```
I/flutter ( 9907): 3-2022-12-09 04:23:16.804353 -- MqttConnectionKeepAlive::pingRequired
    I/flutter ( 9907): 3-2022-12-09 04:23:16.866248 -- MqttConnectionKeepAlive::pingRequired - NOT sending ping - not connected
    I/flutter ( 9907): 3-2022-12-09 04:23:16.866614 -- MqttConnectionKeepAlive::pingRequired - restarting ping timer
```

I did have function for callback ping here

```
MqttServerClient client =
    MqttServerClient(MqttConstants.broker, MqttConstants.clientId);

Future<Stream<List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage>>>?> mqttSubscribe(
    {required String topic}) async {
  // init client
  client = MqttServerClient(MqttConstants.broker, MqttConstants.clientId);
  client.port = MqttConstants.port;
  client.autoReconnect = true;
  client.logging(on: true);
  client.keepAlivePeriod = 60;
  client.pongCallback = pong;
  client.onDisconnected = onDisconnected;

  final connMess = MqttConnectMessage()
      .authenticateAs(MqttConstants.username, MqttConstants.password)
      .withClientIdentifier(MqttConstants.clientId)
      .withWillQos(MqttQos.atLeastOnce)
      .startClean(); // Non persistent session for testing
  print('EXAMPLE::Mqtt client connecting....');
  client.connectionMessage = connMess;

  // Connect to mqtt broker
  try {
    await client.connect();
    // if connected, subscribe to a topic
    if (client.connectionStatus?.state == MqttConnectionState.connected) {
      // subscribe to topic
      client.subscribe(topic, MqttQos.atMostOnce);
      return client.updates;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } on NoConnectionException catch (e) {
    log(e.toString());
  }
}

void pong() {
  print('ping response arrived');
}

void onDisconnected() {
  print('disconnected');
}
```

What's the problem? I'm confuse since before this, it can be run smoothly..

Comment: What address are you using for the broker?

Comment: @hardillb I'm using the server name that I set for the mqtt broker

Comment: Which resolves to what IP address?

Comment: @hardillb Hi you, I already solved this problem. Thank you for everything. Have a nice day!

Comment: Then post an answer with a description of how you solved it so others can benefit

Comment: @hardillb Hi sorry for the late reply. I'm using Node-Red to create my MQTT broker, this problem happened cause I'm using same unique ID and topics for other MQTT broker. After changing it, the apps run smoothly. Thank you once again!

Comment: Please post a proper answer (the big box under the question) not a comment. Answered questions score higher in the search results